# WoL while laptop lid is closed

Tags: 20.04, power-management, laptop, lid, wakeonlan

Hope you can help me with this problem.

Namely, I have an old Asus laptop that I use as my home server.

It's runnung Ubuntu Server LTS 20.04.

I'm able to suspend it and wake it up by using $systemctl suspend and $wakeonlan MACaddr (from a different machine) respectively while the laptop lid is open.

When I close the lid, I'm able to suspend it, but unable to wake it up.

Is there a way to wake up the laptop from a suspended mode with wakeonlan while the lid is closed?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Doubt it. All guides out there state to DISABLE suspend/sleep/hibernate. If you want WOL to work the system needs to be powered off.

Comment: I tried powering it off but I'm unable to wake it up with wakeonlan. I've read that some NICs don't listen for magic packets while the machine is powered off, is that true? Thank you for taking your time to comment, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Yes that is true; not all NICs support it and also some MOBOs don't too. If that is the case your system and/or your NIC does not support this

Comment: Got it, thank you for info!